# Junit how to mock method return in test method?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit, mocking

I was getting a NullPointerException with following method's test but after comments I edited my code and now getting following error:

org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type ...

My source code is at *src/main/java* and test is at *src/test/java* but this doesnt play much of a big role, I moved the test class in main/java and didnt help.

```
@Component
public class MyClass {

@Autowired
MyService myService;

public void myMethod(Dog dog, Animal animal) { 
    if (myService.isAnimal(dog.getStatus()) {//NPE was on this line
      dog.setName("mike");
    } else {
      dog.setName(null);
    }
}
}
```

Below is test code:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = MyClass.class)
public class MyClassTest {

@Autowired
MyClass testObjMyClass;

@Test
public void testMyMethod() {

MyService myService = mock(MyService.class);

Dog dog = new Dog();
dog.setStatus("Y"); // this should give true for isAnimal()
when(myService.isAnimal(dog.getStatus())).thenReturn(true); // I tried with ("Y") as well

testObjMyClass.myMethod(dog, animal);// I defined animal in test Class variables before.
assertEquals("mike", dog.getName());
}

}
```

My project is springboot application, myService is autowired in myMethod(). I would appreciuate your tips!

Comment: is this a unit test or iIT test?

Comment: I dont know what ilT test is, I just right click in class an say Run As Junit test

Comment: You initialize myService but don't pass it to method.. or anywhere.. If you do then post whole test file, llooks like myService is null, so look around it or post it here

Comment: I updated the code. myService belongs to the class, it isnt a parameter for the method.

Comment: have you `@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)` annotation in class where test belongs?

Comment: No I just added it and after importing RunWith I get following error: Class<SpringJUnit4ClassRunner> cannot be resolved to a type

Comment: I added the import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner; but still getting NPE at same line this time with more trace...

Comment: Dont know if you have copied sourcecode or write it.. but your class has a name starting with lowercase `myClass` and in test you use uppercase `MyClass.class`.. java is case sensitive

Comment: copy paste error, it is of course ´MyClass´

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mocking the class `MyService` but you are not injecting that mock into `MyClass`.
Try this if you are using mockito

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MyClassTest {

            @Mock
            MyService myService;

            @InjectMocks
            MyClass testObjMyClass;

            @Before
            public void setup() {
                MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
                when(myService.isAnimal(dog.getStatus())).thenReturn(true);
            }

            @Test
            public void testMyMethod() {

                Dog dog = new Dog();
                dog.setStatus("Y"); // this should give true for isAnimal()

                testObjMyClass.myMethod(dog, animal);// I defined animal in test Class variables before.
                assertEquals("mike", dog.getName());
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have spring boot 1.4 or above try to replace annotation in test with these:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment=WebEnvironment.NONE)
```

It's simplification created by Spring team

If you have Spring boot lower than 1.4 (i.e. 1.3) the you have to add loader to your `ContextConfiguration`:

```
@ContextConfiguration(classes=MyClass.class, loader=SpringApplicationContextLoader.class)
```

Comment: I have Spring Boot Starter Parent 2.1.4 in my pom file, and Im getting without ContextConfiguration the same error and when I add ContextConfiguration, I get SpringApplicationContextLoader not definet. import org.springframework.boot.test.SpringApplicationContextLoader doesnt help either.